# Спецсимволы в названии таблицы postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Хочу создать таблицу, имя которой будет `test'"@#$%^&\`, но обычной командой 
`CREATE TABLE test'"@#$%^&\` это не удается из-за спецсимволов. Как это можно сделать? СУБД - postgresql.

Comment: заключить имя в двойные кавычки. правда саму двойную кавычку в названии видимо надо попробовать заэкранировать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня на 9.6 вот так работает:

```
CREATE TABLE public."test'""@#$%^&\"
```

Answer (score 1):

Если не знаете как правильно экранировать имя объекта - можно позвать на помощь функцию `quote_ident` и синтаксис [Dollar-quoted String](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS):

```
melkij=> select quote_ident ($$test'"@#$%^&\$$);
   quote_ident    
------------------
 "test'""@#$%^&\"
(1 строка)
```

Полученный литерал будет синтаксически допустимым именем объекта который можно использовать в частности в `create table`

```
melkij=> create table "test'""@#$%^&\" ();
CREATE TABLE
melkij=> select * from pg_tables where tablename = $$test'"@#$%^&\$$;
-[ RECORD 1 ]--------------
schemaname  | public
tablename   | test'"@#$%^&\
tableowner  | melkij
tablespace  | 
hasindexes  | f
hasrules    | f
hastriggers | f
rowsecurity | f
```